# Web Scraping for optimal price?

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping

This website compares all prices in most of the stores in my country for a certain Magic: The Gathering card https://www.ligamagic.com.br/?view=cards%2Fsearch&card=

I would like to code a program that:

1 -> Asks me for a list of cards(with amount)

2 -> I insert the cards i want to buy

3 -> Program shows the optimal way to buy those cards.

Shipping is usually $7 in any store.

The program must tell me what is the optimal way to buy all cards i'v inserted(the cheapest way). It must show multiple stores based on shipping cost, if that way is cheaper.

My problem is: I'm not sure where do i start.
What should i learn for this very specific case? Phyton web scraping? Excel web scraping?

**I'm open on learning code language, watching video tutorials, etc. Anything that will help me with this.**

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Well, you could start by learning code language, watching video tutorials, etc. It's possible to do it with Python, so if you don't know Python learn it, and if you do learn scraping. If you know what to look for I don't see the issue.

Comment: Are you asking us to code your project ? Start with something, if you face some issues while coding ask help here.

Comment: Side note: we also do not recommend specific tutorials or other off-site resources. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more information about what questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'v shown an specific problem I want to solve and I'm asking where to start.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you will run into here is that the scraping of every single site your program will search for cards will require unique code. The html of every site will be organized differently, and you will have to dissect this html to determine how the card data is represented for every website. If you are willing to write unique code for each site's html to search for the specific card data, then I would recommend the following:

- Use Selenium webdriver as suggested above (fairly easy to learn) with phantomjs (it is headless so it is faster).

  1. For each potential site that could contain the card, write a function that directs the phantom js driver to that sites url and then use FindElement to find the search bar element. Then use the SendKeys method to send the name of an individual card to the search bar, then use the Click method on the search button.
  2. The driver will then be directed to the page with search results. Here is where you will have to use a tool such as chrome developer tools to inspect the html of the page and determine how the card data (name, price, etc) is presented. Once you have dissected the html, you can have your program use FindElement to get this data. Store it in some kind of collection to return to your main function.
  3. Repeat these steps, writing a unique scrape function for each website that you plan to search.
  4. From your main function, call each of the above scrape functions, and compare the results of each to find the optimal price.

This is a very high level explanation but if you understand the basics of a language such as python or c#, then it will be easy to teach yourself selenium and phantomjs, and this will be fairly easy to implement.

Comment: https://www.ligamagic.com.br/?view=cards%2Fsearch&card= have the same listing pattern for any card you request

Comment: Yes the listing pattern is the same for every card on that site. As is the case for every website (all cards will be listed the same within that site). But he plans to search multiple sites. Each site's listing pattern will be unique. Hence he needs a separate scraping function for every site he plans to search.

Comment: No need to scrape every store. We only need to gather Ligamagic's info. Such as: [Store name+Card Name+Price].

Answer (score 1):

You could use Selenium driver to drive the browser from a coding language of your choice. It takes a bit of setting up but it's not too difficult.

I think the problem you'd find here is twofold. Firstly you'll need to understand where to look (i.e. what sites are selling) and then come up with some heuristic that defines how you figured out where to look such that your program will be able to uncover new purchasing sources as the web changes dynamically (i.e. sites go offline, shops shutdown, new ones open and stock runs out). Secondly you'll need to figure out how to make the program factor in things such as shipping cost, taxes and the like (this information will not be available in the same format or same place from each of the sites that the program will be scraping).

I hope this was helpful?